# sharedPreference: write something and save it, everything disappears

Tags: java, android

I am working on this app where I have one `EditText` field where you can write something and then it get saved and added to a list(`TextView`). I save the content of the `EditText` in this way:

```
saved += "*" + editTextFelt.getText().toString() + ". \n";
```

`saved` is a `String`. 
Everything works fine, I can even reload the app and it's still displayed in the `TextView`, but if I try to write something and save it everything that was there, now disappears. Why?

CODE:
init Method()

```
sp = getSharedPreferences(fileName, 0);
betaView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.betaTextView);
```

I've got a button to send the text, and this is like:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnSend:
            saved += "*" + editTextFelt.getText().toString() + ". \n";
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putString("SAVED", saved);
            editor.commit();

            betaView.setText(sp.getString("SAVED", "Empty"));
```

Comment: You need to show us how you are saving and loading the data to the SharedPreference.

Comment: I understand, Ill try to post just what's important in my code!
Ive got a init Method where I have:
sp = getSharedPreferences(fileName, 0);
betaView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.betaTextView);

And I got a OnclickLisener with the following code:
  case R.id.btnSend:
   saved += "*" + editTextFelt.getText().toString() + ". \n";
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
   editor.putString("SAVED", saved);
   editor.commit();
   
   betaView.setText(sp.getString("SAVED", "Empty"));

Comment: By the way when Im writing a comment all the text gets wrapped up:/

Comment: How are you initializing/setting value to `saved` for the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you saving it? because when you save a text against a variable it replaces the previous one.

So you need to get the previous one and then append the new one and then again save it to `SharedPreferences`, something like this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String saved = sp.getString("YourVariable", "");
saved += "*" + editTextFelt.getText().toString() + ". \n"; //appending previous
//Editor to edit
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("YourVariable",saved);
editor.commit(); //don't forget to commit.
```

now set this appended text to your `TextView` like this:

```
betaView.setText(saved);
```

Comment: Oh! I added  saved = sp.getString("SAVED", "");
  betaView.setText(saved);
In the onCreate, and then it worked! So thank's alot for the help Adil!Now I did get it to work! , awesome!